# Plot a frame when encountering empty vectors in R?

Tags: r, function, plot, lapply

Suppose I have three vectors, one empty (here `x.y1`) and others not empty (here `x.y2` and `x.y3`). **My goal** is for empty vectors, an empty plot be plotted (just a frame with nothing in it).

Given my plotting plan detailed below, is it possible that before the final plotting by `lapply` I could have a function that would check if the vector is empty and then `lpply` just create a frame for plot (e.g., `plot.new() ; box()`) for the empty vectors to be plotted?

```
x.y1 = c()
x.y2 = c(2, 3)
x.y3 = c(6, 2)

m = matrix(1:3); layout(m)

plot.names = noquote(paste0("x.y", 1:3))

lapply(plot.names, plot) 

# Error: need finite 'ylim' values # Right now I get this error due to the empty vector!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
lapply(mget(plot.names), function(a) 
    if(is.null(a)){
        plot(0,0, type = "n")
        }else{
            plot(a)
            })
```